# URL path similarity/string similarity algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, classification, levenshtein-distance, text-mining

My problem is that I need to compare URL paths and deduce if they are similar. Below I provide example data to process:

```
# GROUP 1
/robots.txt

# GROUP 2
/bot.html

# GROUP 3
/phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc1/scripts/setup.php
/phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc2/scripts/setup.php
/phpMyAdmin-2.5.6/scripts/setup.php
/phpMyAdmin-2.5.7-pl1/scripts/setup.php
/phpMyAdmin-2.5.7/scripts/setup.php
/phpMyAdmin-2.6.0-alpha/scripts/setup.php
/phpMyAdmin-2.6.0-alpha2/scripts/setup.php

# GROUP 4
//phpMyAdmin/
```

I tried Levenshtein distance to compare, but for me is not enough accurate. I do not need 100% accurate algorithm, but I think 90% and above is a must.

I think that I need some sort of classifier, but the problem is that each portion of new data can containt path that should be classified to the new unknown class.

Could you please direct me to the right thoutht?

Thanks

Comment: So, basically, you have a set of URLs and you want to divide it into disjunctive sets (do the [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)), or what is your task more precisely? I guess also, the number of classes is not known a priori, right?

Comment: *disjunctive -> disjoint

Comment: Yes you are right, my task is some kind of clustering. The problem is that data come all the time, so algorithm should adapt to new data - number of classes can raise. This task is preprocessing data to use them in next step. What I want to achieve is to get knowledge which application/script has been requested, for me there is no difference if it was phpMyAdmin version 2.5.6 or 2.6.0 - I need to know that phpMyAdmin setup.php script was requested. I hope this helps you to understand my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking @jakub.gieryluk suggestion I accidentally have found solution that satisfy me - "Hobohm clustering algorithm, originally devised to reduce redundancy of biological sequence data sets."

Tests of PERL library implemented by [Bruno Vecchi](http://search.cpan.org/~brunov/String-Cluster-Hobohm-0.112890/lib/String/Cluster/Hobohm.pm) gave me really good results. The only problem is that I need Python implementation, but I belive that I can either find one on the Internet or reimplement code by myself.

Next thing is that I have not checked active learning ability of this algorithm yet ;)

Comment: This is the exact thing I was looking for. Did you made progress about it?

Comment: Maybe this can help you --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/67293055/1514627 ( nodejs )

Answer (score 1):

Levenshtein distance is best option, but tuned distance. You have to use weighted Edit distance and possibly split path on tokens - words and numbers. So for example version like "2.5.6-rc2 and 2.5.6" can be treated as 0 weight difference, but name token like phpMyAdmin and javaMyAdmin give 1 weight difference.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the exact answer to your question, but are you familiar with [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) algorithm?

I guess even the Levenshtein can work here, the difficulty however is how to compute centroids with that approach.

Perhaps you can divide input set into disjoint subsets, then for each URL in each subset compute the distance to all the other URLs in the same subset, and the URL that has lowest sum of distances, should be the centroid (of course, it depends on how big is the input set; for huge sets it might be not a good idea to do so).

The good thing about k-means is that you can start with absolutely random division, and then iteratively make it better.

The bad thing about k-means is that you have to precise `k` before start. However, during the run (perhaps where the situation stabilized after first couple of iterations), you can measure intra-similarity of each set, and if it is low, you can divide the set into two subsets and go on with the same algorithm.