# Group similar strings from an array in Node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, string, comparison

Let's say I have a collection of different URLs in an array:

```
var source = ['www.xyz.com/Product/1', 'www.xyz.com/Product/3', 'www.xyz.com/Category/1', 'somestring']
```

What would be a good way to iterate over the array and group similar strings into a separate array?
The desired output from the example above would be:

```
var output = [
    ['www.xyz.com/Product/1', 'www.xyz.com/Product/3'],
    ['www.xyz.com/Category/1'],
    ['somestring']
];
```

**Conditions**

- All items within `source` can be random strings
- The logic must be able to compare and group around 100'000 items in a meaningful time

I found the [string-similarity library](https://github.com/aceakash/string-similarity) which gives the possibility to compare one string against a collection of strings. One way would be to iterate over the source, compare each item against the source collection and apply a rule to group items with a similar score. However I guess this would be terrible inefficient.

Can someone suggest me an efficient way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: so in the example there's a clear pattern, but it seems like you're asking about strings that could be anything? is that correct?

Comment: @aw04 Yes, there is no clear pattern the strings could be anything. As I wrote: All items within source can be random strings

Comment: good luck then :)

Comment: just a note though, the similar score idea is too simple, you're only seeing how one string relates to another, not how they all relate together. only thing i can think is to go through a first time and figure out your different array groups somehow, but that sounds like a pretty complex algorithm

Comment: You're totally right but I think there must already exist an algorithm to accomplish this sort of comparison (mb not implemented in Node.js) which I'm just not aware of. So I hope someone pushes me in the right direction :)

Comment: [Sorting Algorithms Animations](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms) illustrates how effectively data sets from different starting points can be sorted using different algorithms.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809134/url-path-similarity-string-similarity-algorithm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to compare the strings with each other and test how different they are. There is an algorithm that does that, which is the [Levenshtein distance](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=levenshtein%20distance&oq=levenshtein%20distance&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l2j0l2j69i61.4536j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) algorithm:

> The Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the
>   difference between two sequences. Informally, the Levenshtein distance
>   between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits
>   (i.e. insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one
>   word into the other.

---

We can easily create a Levenshtein filter on top of [fast-levenshtein module](https://github.com/hiddentao/fast-levenshtein):

```
const levenshtein = require('fast-levenshtein'); 

const levenshteinFilter = (source, maximum = 5) => {
  let _source, matches, x, y;
  _source = source.slice();
  matches = [];
  for (x = _source.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    let output = _source.splice(x, 1);
    for (y = _source.length - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
      if (levenshtein.get(output[0], _source[y]) <= maximum) {
        output.push(_source[y]);
        _source.splice(y, 1);
        x--;
      }
    }
    matches.push(output);
  }
  return matches;
}

let source = ['www.xyz.com/Product/1', 'www.xyz.com/Product/3', 'www.xyz.com/Category/1', 'somestring'];
let output = levenshteinFilter(source);
// [ [ 'www.xyz.com/Product/1', 'www.xyz.com/Product/3' ],
//   [ 'www.xyz.com/Category/1' ],
//   [ 'somestring' ] ]
```

You can define the maximum acceptable distance in the 2 argument of the function (defaults to 5).

Comment: Even though I proposed a library using the same algorithm your solution is working. I haven't measured the performance yet but thank you for the answer!

Comment: Should be `levenshtein.get(`?

Comment: @JohnJones Thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 2):

How about MinHash (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash)?

It was designed to find duplicate web pages. So I suppose you can url.split('/') and treat each url as a set of words.

Comment: This looks interesting. I'm going to have a deeper look, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't flesh out your intent but if faced with the task of finding a selected items nearest neighbors from a random haystack I'd probably try to build a tree of hashes.

Or, and this might be cheating, I'd let a library do it for me. [lunr.js](http://lunrjs.com/) is basically a pure JS lucene index, I'd push your array into it and query against that to get similar strings. I've had pretty large datasets in lunr.js before and it is highly performant, no candle to having an elasticsearch cluster nearby but still damn impressive.

If you provide some more detail on what you're trying to do I could give some more details and maybe even some example code.

Answer (score 0):

If source contains all random urls, below function will give the expected output as shown in the question.

```
function filter (source) {
  var output = []
  source.forEach((svalue) => {
    if (output.length === 0) {
      output.push([svalue])
    } else {
      var done = false
      output.forEach((tarr) => {
        if (!done) {
          tarr.forEach((tvalue) => {
            if (svalue.indexOf('/') > -1 && svalue.split('/').slice(0, 2).join('/') == tvalue.split('/').slice(0, 2).join('/')) {
              tarr.push(svalue)
              done = true
            }
          })
        }
      })
      if (!done) {
        output.push([svalue])
        done = true
      }
    }
  })
  return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example tests, I can suggest you to implement a [Radix Tree or  Prefix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) to store strings. After that you may to define a criteria to cluster those strings.

Answer (score 0):

I modified user7560588's code to user string-similarity based on Dice's Coefficient, which is mostly better than Levenshtein distance. https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity.

You can adjust the rate of acceptance from 0 - 1 being 1 is 100% match. So it has a better resolution for you to set a correct acceptance value.

What it does is it loops the value in the array and compare 2 strings and group them if match.
This library can also compare a string to an array of strings and return the corresponding rating in an array.

```
var stringSimilarity = require("string-similarity");

const stringFilter = (source, rate = 0.85) => {
  let _source, matches, x, y;
  _source = source.slice();
  matches = [];
  for (x = _source.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    let output = _source.splice(x, 1);

    for (y = _source.length - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
      var match = stringSimilarity.compareTwoStrings(output[0], _source[y]);
      console.log(output[0], _source[y], match);
      if (match > rate) {
        output.push(_source[y]);
        _source.splice(y, 1);
        x--;
      }
    }
    matches.push(output);
  }
  return matches;
};

let source = ['www.xyz.com/Product/1', 'www.xyz.com/Product/3', 'www.xyz.com/Category/1', 'somestring'];
let output = stringFilter(source);
console.log(output);
```

Results

```
somestring www.xyz.com/Category/1 0.06666666666666667
somestring www.xyz.com/Product/3 0.06896551724137931
somestring www.xyz.com/Product/1 0.06896551724137931
www.xyz.com/Category/1 www.xyz.com/Product/3 0.5365853658536586
www.xyz.com/Category/1 www.xyz.com/Product/1 0.5853658536585366
www.xyz.com/Product/3 www.xyz.com/Product/1 0.95
[
  [ 'somestring' ],
  [ 'www.xyz.com/Category/1' ],
  [ 'www.xyz.com/Product/3', 'www.xyz.com/Product/1' ]
]
```